# Printing multiple sprites from an ArrayList - LOGCAT

Tags: android, loops, sprite

I'm trying to create 2 for loops that loop and add a certain amount of sprites, then go through another loop and print the sprites. However it just seems to crash. In the ***update*** method it adds the sprites to the array list and in the ***Do draw*** method it prints them out. Logcat is below too. Thanks.

```
  package cct.mad.lab;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

/**
 * This class takes care of surface for drawing and touches
 * 
 */

public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    /* Member (state) fields   */
    private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
    private Paint paint; //Reference a paint object 
    /** The drawable to use as the background of the animation canvas */
    private Bitmap mBackgroundImage;
    private Sprite sprite;
    int arraySize;
    private int hitCount;

    private ArrayList<Sprite> spritesArrayList;

    int count = 5;
    int finalScore;
    private boolean gameOver;
    /* For the countdown timer */
    private long  startTime ;           //Timer to count down from
    private final long interval = 1 * 1000;     //1 sec interval
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;  //Reference to class
    private boolean timerRunning = false;
    private String displayTime;         //To display time on the screen

    private Bitmap spritebmp;


    public GameView(Context context) {

        super(context);
        // Focus must be on GameView so that events can be handled.
        this.setFocusable(true);
        // For intercepting events on the surface.
        this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        mBackgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.background2);
        spritesArrayList= new ArrayList<Sprite>();
    }



    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                spritesArrayList.add(sprite);
            }
        mBackgroundImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackgroundImage, getWidth(), getHeight(), true);
        ResetGame();
        gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this.getHolder(), this);
        gameLoopThread.running = true;
        gameLoopThread.start();

    }

    //To initialise/reset game
    private void ResetGame(){
        gameOver = false;
        hitCount = 0;
        sprite = new Sprite(this);
        /* Set paint details */
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
        paint.setTextSize(20);

        //Set timer
        startTime = 60;//Start at 10s to count down
        //Create new object - convert startTime to milliseconds
        countDownTimer=new MyCountDownTimer(startTime*1000,interval);
        countDownTimer.start();//Start it running
        timerRunning = true;

    }
    public void GetArrayListSize()
    {
    if(spritesArrayList.isEmpty())
    {
    //nothing
    }
    else
    {
    arraySize = spritesArrayList.size();
    }
    }

    //This class updates and manages the assets prior to drawing - called from the Thread
    public void update(){
        if (gameOver != true)
        {
        sprite.update();
        }

         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
         {              
             sprite = new Sprite(this);
             spritesArrayList.add(sprite);
         }
    }
    /**
     * To draw the game to the screen
     * This is called from Thread, so synchronisation can be done
     */

    public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         Paint textPaint = new Paint();

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
        //Draw all the objects on the canvas
        canvas.drawText("The Game ",5,25, paint);
        canvas.drawText("Score: " + hitCount, 5, 50, paint);
        canvas.drawText("Time: " +displayTime, 5, 75, paint);
        GetArrayListSize();

         //Loop for sprite creation
         for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) 
         {          
            Sprite sprite = spritesArrayList.get(i);
            sprite.draw(canvas);
         }



        if (gameOver == true)
        {
            canvas.drawText("Final Score: "+finalScore, 5,100, paint);
            int width = this.getMeasuredWidth()/2;
            int height = this.getMeasuredHeight()/2;
            textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
            canvas.drawText("GAME OVER - PRESS BACK BUTTON TO RETURN", width, height, textPaint);
        }

    }
    public int getHitCount()
    {
        return hitCount;
    }
    //To be used if we need to find where screen was touched
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (gameOver != true)
        {

            if (sprite.wasItTouched(event.getX(), event.getY()))
                {

                sprite = new Sprite(this);

                    hitCount++;         
                }

        }
        return true;
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        gameLoopThread.running = false;

        // Shut down the game loop thread cleanly.
        boolean retry = true;
        while(retry) {
            try {
                gameLoopThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }
    private class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

          public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
                super(startTime, interval);
          }
          public void onFinish() {
                displayTime = "Times Over!";
                finalScore = hitCount;
                gameOver = true;
                timerRunning = false;
                countDownTimer.cancel();
          }
          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                displayTime = " " + millisUntilFinished / 1000;
          }
        }//End of MyCountDownTimer



}
```

**LogCat**

```
    05-04 13:24:27.654: E/AndroidRuntime(1448): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-99
05-04 13:24:27.654: E/AndroidRuntime(1448): Process: cct.mad.lab, PID: 1448
05-04 13:24:27.654: E/AndroidRuntime(1448): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-04 13:24:27.654: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-04 13:24:27.654: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
05-04 13:24:27.654: E/AndroidRuntime(1448):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
```

Comment: How big is the image `R.drawable.background2`? Android has a quite limited fixed size image buffer ...

Comment: Hi - found out it's not the background. the for loop in the update method fills up the Array so much it runs out of memory. Can't figure out why the loop isn't stopping after 5.

Comment: How about `for (Sprite sprite: spritesArrayList) {` in the first place. Should be a lot less error prone.

Comment: Hi - I've added this, however 
after (Sprite sprite: spritesArrayList), in the loop, the first line (Sprite sprite = spritesArrayList.get(i);) sprite is underlined because there's a duplicate variable

Comment: That for(each) loop already takes care of the variable assignment. The second declaration is not necessary any more. `for (Sprite sprite: spritesArrayList)` essentially means *give me all objects from that list in order*. Saves you the fiddling around with the indexes and is probably also faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your global Variables.
Please check this line

```
private ArrayList<Sprite> spritesArrayList;
int arraySize = spritesArrayList.size();
```

I think the  **`private ArrayList<Sprite> spritesArrayList`;** is null at this time and on the next line you are trying to get its size at the moment;

**EDIT:**

I think you should make a method that return the size of this arraylist like this algorithm

```
public void GetArrayListSize()
{
if( arraylist is empty)
{
//nothing
}
else
{
arraySize = spritesArrayList.size();
}
}
```

and call this method whenever you want to get the size of this arraylist

EDIT 2:

change

```
int arraySize = spritesArrayList.size();
```

to

```
arraySize = spritesArrayList.size();
```

in your GetArrayListSize() method

Comment: Hi - I got rid of arraySize and changed the for loop so it just go the size at the beginning of the loop rather than putting it into a variable. However, when I run the game, none of the canvas draws work and no sprites spawn. :(

Comment: ok thats another problem but  you want to get the ArrayList size right ?

Comment: Yes so it will run through the for loop located in the doDraw method. I take it the array isn't being populated because no sprites are spawning

Comment: call the GetArrayListSize method before the for loop.. i think you problem is solved then..

Comment: Updated code - called the method before the loop but still nothing.

Comment: change  int arraySize = spritesArrayList.size(); to  arraySize = spritesArrayList.size();

Comment: I removed the int and declared it at the top again, changed the for loop to arraySize instead of the get size method, still no sprites spawning. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76917/discussion-between-softcoder-and-saffa).